# Replacing Exclamation with Dot in a string

Tags: c++, string, replace

I'm asked to replace all the exclamations with dots in a string. I came up with a function but i'm getting an error because it doesn't change the last exclamation. It is just the last exclamation.

The input is:

We'll continue our quest in space. There will be more shuttle flights and more shuttle crews and, yes, more volunteers, more civilians, more teachers in space. Nothing ends here; our hopes and our journeys continue!

My function is:

```
string ReplaceExclamation(string text)
{
string newText = text;
int i, len = text.size();

for(i=0; i<len; i++)
{

if(text[i] == '!')
newText[i] = '.';
}
return newText;
}
```

Does anybody know how to hardcore it since it's just the last exclamation.
Thanks

Comment: How does the full function look like? Does it return `text` or `newText`? How do you call this function? Can you please try to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and show us?

Comment: I've tried your code on my box, it works fine:
We'll continue our quest in space. There will be more shuttle flights and more shuttle crews and, yes, more volunteers, more civilians, more teachers in space. Nothing ends here; our hopes and our journeys continue.

Comment: [cannot reproduce](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/1bfe589f6a9d170f)

Comment: Something must go wrong in the way you call the function. Can you post everything?

Comment: I call it in main as a menu option. It is a program called Authoring assistant. I'm suppose to ask user for a string and edit it with his/her option from the menu that i provide MENU
c - Number of non-whitespace characters
w - Number of words
f - Find text
r - Replace all !'s
s - Shorten spaces
q - Quit

Choose an option:

Comment: the function works correctly.. But can you use the `replace` function from `STL` rather than writing your own function?

Comment: Im getting this  Unit test   0/2
Test that ReplaceExclamation() works correctly 
Test feedback
ReplaceExclamation() incorrectly edits the string.
Result: We'll continue our quest in space.  There will be more shuttle flights and more shuttle crews and,  yes,  more volunteers, more civilians,  more teachers in space.  Nothing ends here;  our hopes and our journeys continue!

Comment: The question really is unanswerable right now. Your function has been shown to work correctly. You have not provided a complete example, explained in the link from the first comment. We can't simply guess the problem you're having. We need a solid example that we can test ourselves to get the same result. If it works for us and not you, there's some necessary information missing from the question.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the [std::replace](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/replace) algorithm function to replace the exclamation characters with dots:

```
std::replace(s1.begin(), s1.end(), '!', '.');
```

Make sure you include the `<algorithm>` header.

Answer (score 0):

string library's length function does not include the '\0' character at the end of the string. So you can try len+1 as your terminating condition in your for loop.

```
string ReplaceExclamation(string text)
{ 
string newText = text;
int i, len = text.size();

for(i=0; i<len+1; i++)
{

if(text[i] == '!')
newText[i] = '.';
}
return newText;
}
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Why would this help? At best, you're checking the null terminator and adding an extra iteration plus confusion from inconsistent rules about indexing past the length. At worst, you're using a dialect of C++ where this is undefined behaviour.